# nftables: isolate VLANs with some exceptions

Tags: networking, routing, firewall, vlan, nftables

Say there is a custom router (a Raspberry Pi box) with Debian 11 and nftables installed, with a single physical Ethernet inferface and the following VLANs configured:

- eth0.501 192.168.41.0/24 CCTV cameras
- eth0.502 192.168.42.0/24 Home
  automation
- eth0.503 192.168.43.0/24 Guest network (with a separate WiFi AP attached to it)
- eth0.504 192.168.44.0/24 Personal trusted network with sensible data freely available on Samba shares
- eth0.505 192.168.45.0/24 Fibre ONT network (remotely accessible by the ISP)

The desired policies are:

- CCTV cannot access any other network but can be accessed by Home Automation and Personal Trusted networks and none else.
- Home Automation can only access CCTV and the Internet, can only be accessed by Personal Trusted network.
- Guest can only access the Internet, can only be accessed by Personal Trusted network.
- Personal Trusted network is not accessible from outside it at all, but can access all other networks.
- Fibre ONT network can only be accessible by some of the other networks (as above) but itself cannot access any of them.

By "no access" I mean no visibility whatsoever, not even ping. This is the main point of the VLANs here, but the Pi router will let anyone see everyone unless restricted by nftables (or iptables, which I don't want to deal with).

Conversely, where access to a network is granted, for simplicity let's assume that all IPs, ports and protocols are allowed.

Can someone please give some examples how nftables can be configured from scratch to achieve (some of) the above goals? What tables, chains and filters need to be setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need any special tables or chains:

1. Start with the default `forward` chain in the default 'inet filter' table that your OS usually fills in in the distributed /etc/nftables.conf example – in other words, the equivalent of iptables' built-in "FORWARD chain.
2. Add the usual conntrack rule, `ct state {established, related} accept` if it's not there already. This will handle replies returning in the opposite direction.
3. Add a series of `ip saddr ... ip daddr ... accept` rules exactly according to your description. (Though maybe first reformulate "X can be accessed by Y" as "Y can access X" to make things more consistent.)

   - "Access Internet but not LAN" can be written as `ip daddr != 192.168.0.0/16`.
   - IPv6 needs a second rule with `ip6 saddr` / `ip6 daddr`.
   - Define $macros using `define guest = 192.168.43.0/24` at the top of nftables.conf to make it clearer what addresses or interfaces mean what.
   - You can use an inline set `{x, y, z}` wherever a value can be used, so that a single rule can allow from multiple sources and/or to multiple destinations.

   If this is the only gateway, interface-based `iifname "..." oifname "..." accept` may be simpler than IP-based rules.
4. Finally add a `drop` or `reject` rule at the end. (I prefer "reject with icmpx admin-prohibited".)

Hopefully your Pi is a recent model with the Ethernet port not being USB-attached anymore.